# Angular Material CDK Drag and Drop: Style preview element conditionally

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have two lists with the `cdkDropList` directive from [Angular Material CDK](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropList). Let's call them *list 1* and *list 2*. The list items contain images. The lists are not next to each other, so there are some other DOM elements between (I call it *"empty space"*). When dragging an item from one list to the other I see a preview of the dragged item (the image).

```html
<!-- list 1 -->
<ul cdkDropList>
 <li *ngFor="..." cdkDrag>
  <img src="..." />
 </li>
</ul>

<!-- some other DOM elements -->

<!-- list 2 -->
<ul cdkDropList>
 <li *ngFor="..." cdkDrag>
  <img src="..." />
 </li>
</ul>
```

So far, so good.

What I want to achieve is to style the image conditionally (e.g. by placing a red border around it) but only if the dragged element is not either over list 1 or list 2. I got it to work halfway by using the `*cdkDragPreview` directive and setting a class conditionally by updating a field `previewIsDraggedOutsideContainer` in the `*.ts` file

```html
<!-- component.html -->
<ul cdkDropList>
 <li *ngFor="..." cdkDrag
    (cdkDragMoved)="onMoved($event)"
 >
  <div *cdkDragPreview>
   <div [class.drag-element-preview-warning]="previewIsDraggedOutsideContainer">
    <img src="..." />
   </div>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The field `previewIsDraggedOutsideContainer` is updated by comparing the cursor's position with every move with the bounding box of the DOM element the item is dragged from.

```js
// component.ts
  public onMoved($event: CdkDragMove<any>): void {
    const boundingClientRect = $event.source.dropContainer.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const pointerPosition = $event.pointerPosition;
    const isInEmptySpace =
      pointerPosition.x < boundingClientRect.x ||
      pointerPosition.x > boundingClientRect.x + boundingClientRect.width ||
      pointerPosition.y < boundingClientRect.y ||
      pointerPosition.y > boundingClientRect.y + boundingClientRect.height;
    this.previewIsDraggedOutsideContainer = isInEmptySpace;
  }
```

This works halfway, because the class is correctly added when moving the item outside the original list (e.g. *list 1*). However, it should be removed again when the item is dragged over another CDK-List (e.g. *list 2*). I already tried out working with `cdkDragExited` on the list item or `cdkDropListExited` on the list and setting `previewIsDraggedOutsideContainer = false` there. However, these event emitter only emit when the item is dragged over another DropList and they don't fire again when the dragged item is dragged away again to the *"empty space"*. So I don't see a way I can calculate whether the dragged item is over *any* CDK-Drop-list at any given point of the drag-move. Also I'm not sure if listening to the `cdkDragMoved` event is a good idea because it will probably hurt performance...

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do? And if yes, what's the most elegant way?